Motivic Integral Computation
Let $X$ be a smooth $\mathbb{C}$-variety and $D_1,D_2$ smooth divisors on $X$. I'd like to compute the motivic integral
$$\int_{\mathcal{J}_\infty(X)}\mathbb{L}^{-\operatorname{ord}_{D_1+D_2}}\mathop{d\mu}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\mu\left(\operatorname{ord}_{D_1+D_2}^{-1}(k)\right)\cdot\mathbb{L}^{-k}.$$
I have already computed the motivic integral associated to the divisor $aD$ where $a\in\mathbb{N}$ and $D$ is smooth, so ideally I'd like to use similar techniques.
The computation for $aD$ rests on the observation that the $m^\text{th}$-contact locus of $aD$ is empty whenever $a\not\mid m$, so we must reindex the summation of measures over all $k\in\mathbb N$ for which $a$ is a divisor.
Set $D=D_1+D_2$. We have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{ord}_D^{-1}(m)&=\left\{\gamma\in \mathcal{J}_\infty(X)\mid\operatorname{ord}_{D_1}(\gamma)+\operatorname{ord}_{D_2}(\gamma)=m\right\}\\
&=\coprod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\left\{\gamma\mid\operatorname{ord}_{D_1}(\gamma)=i\right\}\cap \left\{\gamma\mid\operatorname{ord}_{D_2}(\gamma)=m-i\right\}\right)\\
&=\coprod_{i=0}^m\left(\left\{\gamma\mid\operatorname{ord}_{D_1}(\gamma)=i\right\}\cap \left\{\gamma\mid\operatorname{ord}_{D_2}(\gamma)=m-i\right\}\right).
\end{align}
Since $\operatorname{ord}_{D_1}^{-1}(i)=\pi_{i-1}^{-1} \mathcal{J}_{i-1}(D)-\pi_i^{-1} \mathcal{J}_i(D)$ and $$\operatorname{ord}_{D_2}^{-1}(m-i)=\pi_{m-i-1}^{-1} \mathcal{J}_{m-i-1}(D)-\pi_{m-i}^{-1} \mathcal{J}_{m-i}(D),$$
it seems like the remainder of the computation should (perhaps tediously) follow from standard measure-theoretic techniques.
Is there a more efficient way to compute this integral? I'm new to motivic integration, so if possible I'd appreciate a more elementary solution. Thank you for any help!

This integral is easiest to do in the case where D1, D2 intersect transversely, and you can then do the integration locally by fubini since the integrand separates in a nice chart. In general, you can want to first resolve your variety in order to make D1, D2 transverse and then compute on the resolution.

@Asvin: thank you for your response. Could you please elaborate on how to use Fubini's theorem to break up the integrand/separate it in an appropriate chart? It seems to me like I'd need to be integrating over some product of arc spaces in order to invoke this theorem.

I am not sure if there is a Fubini theorem for motivic integration. Motivic integration of an order function of an effective Cartier divisor with normal crossings can be computed explicitly. In general, as noted by Asvin, you can resolve singularities.

By fubini I just mean the simple statement that you can compute the integral of x^ay^b explicitly where x, y are local coordinates. If D1, D2 intersect transversely around a point, then you take x, y to be local coordinates cutting out D1, D2
